# Subset through a list of conditions

Tags: r

I downloaded data using the [eurostat package](http://ropengov.github.io/eurostat/).
Now I want to create a subset that only includes `years > 1989` and countries defined in `country_list`. The countries are splitted into [NUTS-compartments](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/nuts-maps) of increasing resolution that are coded by the scheme AT1, AT11, AT111. I thereby need to add a wildcard to each entry in `country_list`.

```
data_unfiltered <- get_eurostat("demo_r_magec", time_format = "num")
country_list <- list("AT*", "BE*")
data_filtered <- subset(data_unfiltered, time > 1989, geo == country_list[])
```

My most recent version succeeds only in filtering by year. What do I need to add?

Comment: Not really enough information, but if the countries are all 2 characters plus suffix, try something like `country_list <- c("AT", "BE")`; `substr(geo, 1, 2) %in% country_list`. If the country codes have a variable length prefixes, you will have to use a regular expression to parse out the character portion. See `?regex` and `?grep`.

Comment: `data_filtered <- subset(unfiltered_data_demo_r_magec, time > 1989 & substr(geo, 1, 2) %in% country_list)` does the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The format you use to subset multiple conditions may not be correct, try `data_filtered <- subset(data_unfiltered, time > 1989 & geo == country_list[])`

Comment: That gives me `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. `class(data_unfiltered)` is `[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`